# Create ranges from a single list of values that have gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
Modifier    Code
25  92012
25  92014
25  99201
25  99202
25  99203
25  99204
25  99205
25  99211
25  99212
25  99213
25  99214
25  99215
25  99217
25  99218
25  99219
25  99220
25  99221
25  99222
25  99223
25  99224
25  99225
25  99226
25  99231
25  99232
25  99233
25  99234
25  99235
25  99236
25  99238
25  99239
```

And i need to make this table, please help!  Thanks!

```
Modifier    StartCode   EndCode
25  92012   92012
25  92014   92014
25  99201   99205
25  99211   99215
25  99217   99226
25  99231   99236
25  99238   99239
```

Comment: Analytic functions lead/lag.  Offering as much assistance as work shown towards a solution :P http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please search for topics like [gaps and islands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) and attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you still have a problem, please post it with your code, input, output, and expected output.

Comment: Request for code with no evidence that the OP has attempted to solve, or research, the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I had been searching but did not look for Gaps and Islands. Also I'm using SQL 2008 so lead/lag is not available. The Gaps and Island solution helped. Thank You!